# Error making .multi subscription call (Kitties Tutorial)

Tags: polkadot-js

The error I see in the browser console is:

```
VEC: Unable to decode on index 0 createType(Lookup9):: Expected at least 32 bytes (256 bits), found 16 bytes
```

Offending code snippet (from Kitties.js):

```
  // Subscription function to construct all kitty objects
  const subscribeKitties = () => {
    let unsub = null
    const asyncFetch = async () => {
      console.log('Fetching kitties with ids: ' + kittyIds)


      // ***************************************************************
      // The following line throws an error
      unsub = await api.query.substrateKitties.kitties.multi(
        kittyIds,
        kitties => {
          console.log('kitties: ' + kitties)
          const kittiesMap = kitties.map(kitty => parseKitty(kitty.unwrap()))
          console.log(kittiesMap)
          setKitties(kittiesMap)
        }
      )
    }
    asyncFetch()
    return () => {
      unsub && unsub()
    }
  }
```

Full stack trace:

```
2022-05-23 05:24:04             VEC: Unable to decode on index 0 createType(Lookup9):: Expected at least 32 bytes (256 bits), found 16 bytes
apply @ logger.js:62
error @ logger.js:116
decodeVec @ Vec.js:18
Vec @ Vec.js:51
(anonymous) @ Vec.js:59
Type @ registry.js:333
initType @ type.js:35
createTypeUnsafe @ type.js:54
createTypeUnsafe @ registry.js:288
(anonymous) @ bundle.js:334
_formatInputs @ bundle.js:334
(anonymous) @ bundle.js:278
Observable._trySubscribe @ Observable.ts:245
(anonymous) @ Observable.ts:223
errorContext @ errorContext.ts:29
Observable.subscribe @ Observable.ts:221
(anonymous) @ catchError.ts:115
(anonymous) @ lift.ts:24
(anonymous) @ Observable.ts:223
errorContext @ errorContext.ts:29
Observable.subscribe @ Observable.ts:221
(anonymous) @ distinctUntilChanged.ts:157
(anonymous) @ lift.ts:24
(anonymous) @ Observable.ts:223
errorContext @ errorContext.ts:29
Observable.subscribe @ Observable.ts:221
ConnectableObservable.connect @ ConnectableObservable.ts:71
(anonymous) @ refCountDelay.js:17
Observable._trySubscribe @ Observable.ts:245
(anonymous) @ Observable.ts:223
errorContext @ errorContext.ts:29
Observable.subscribe @ Observable.ts:221
(anonymous) @ combineLatest.ts:258
maybeSchedule @ combineLatest.ts:302
_loop_1 @ combineLatest.ts:253
(anonymous) @ combineLatest.ts:252
maybeSchedule @ combineLatest.ts:302
(anonymous) @ combineLatest.ts:237
Observable._trySubscribe @ Observable.ts:245
(anonymous) @ Observable.ts:223
errorContext @ errorContext.ts:29
Observable.subscribe @ Observable.ts:221
(anonymous) @ map.ts:54
(anonymous) @ lift.ts:24
(anonymous) @ Observable.ts:223
errorContext @ errorContext.ts:29
Observable.subscribe @ Observable.ts:221
(anonymous) @ catchError.ts:115
(anonymous) @ lift.ts:24
(anonymous) @ Observable.ts:223
errorContext @ errorContext.ts:29
Observable.subscribe @ Observable.ts:221
(anonymous) @ tap.ts:125
(anonymous) @ lift.ts:24
(anonymous) @ Observable.ts:223
errorContext @ errorContext.ts:29
Observable.subscribe @ Observable.ts:221
(anonymous) @ decorateMethod.js:59
decorateSubscribe @ decorateMethod.js:55
(anonymous) @ decorateMethod.js:74
asyncFetch @ Kitties.js:52
subscribeKitties @ Kitties.js:62
invokePassiveEffectCreate @ react-dom.development.js:23487
callCallback @ react-dom.development.js:3945
invokeGuardedCallbackDev @ react-dom.development.js:3994
invokeGuardedCallback @ react-dom.development.js:4056
flushPassiveEffectsImpl @ react-dom.development.js:23574
unstable_runWithPriority @ scheduler.development.js:468
runWithPriority$1 @ react-dom.development.js:11276
flushPassiveEffects @ react-dom.development.js:23447
(anonymous) @ react-dom.development.js:23324
workLoop @ scheduler.development.js:417
flushWork @ scheduler.development.js:390
performWorkUntilDeadline @ scheduler.development.js:157
Show 44 more frames
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "substrate-front-end-template",
  "version": "monthly-2022-01",
  "private": true,
  "author": "Parity Technologies <admin@parity.io>",
  "license": "Unlicense",
  "homepage": "https://substrate-developer-hub.github.io/substrate-front-end-template",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-front-end-template/issues"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "substrate",
    "substrate-ui",
    "polkadot-js"
  ],
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-app-rewired start",
    "build": "react-app-rewired build",
    "test": "CI=true react-app-rewired test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "eslint:check": "eslint --ext .jsx,.js src/",
    "eslint:write": "eslint --fix --ext .jsx,.js src/",
    "prettier:check": "prettier -c src/*",
    "prettier:write": "prettier -w src/*",
    "deploy": "gh-pages -d build -m '[ci skip] Updates'"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@polkadot/api": "^7.10.1",
    "@polkadot/extension-dapp": "^0.42.7",
    "@polkadot/keyring": "^8.4.1",
    "@polkadot/networks": "^8.4.1",
    "@polkadot/types": "^7.10.1",
    "@polkadot/ui-keyring": "^1.1.1",
    "@polkadot/ui-settings": "^1.1.1",
    "@polkadot/util": "^8.4.1",
    "@polkadot/util-crypto": "^8.4.1",
    "node-polyfill-webpack-plugin": "^1.1.4",
    "prop-types": "^15.8.1",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-copy-to-clipboard": "^5.0.4",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.0",
    "semantic-ui-css": "Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI-CSS#master",
    "semantic-ui-react": "^2.1.2",
    "stream-browserify": "^3.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^8.10.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.4.0",
    "eslint-config-react-app": "^7.0.0",
    "gh-pages": "^3.2.3",
    "prettier": "2.5.1",
    "react-app-rewired": "^2.2.1",
    "semistandard": "^16.0.1"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "6.5.1"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "eslint:recommended",
      "prettier"
    ]
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=16",
    "npm": ">=8"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not ie <= 99",
      "not android <= 4.4.4",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "packageManager": "yarn@3.1.1"
}
```

Comment: "monthly-2022-01" I see used, what node template version are you using? Please do use matching versions!

Comment: Thanks @DanShields. I went through the process from scratch and was careful to use v0.9.19 for the node template as well as the frontend template and I get the same results. I will continue to dig as the problem is likely something I'm doing wrong. Question on versions: Should the template versions match exactly or is v0.9.20 on the frontend expected to be backwards compatible with v0.9.19 on the node, for example?